# How can I covert a varbinary image to render in React js?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, reactjs, image, varbinary

I am trying to display the image in the React profile class component. Format of the image is binary format that is coming from SQL Server and is store in the format of varbinary. This is how I am converting the image.

Image data

```
Picture: {type: "Buffer",…}
data: [67, 58, 92, 68, 65, 84, 69, 78, 92, 71, 73, 69, 66, 46, 78, 69, 84, 92, 72, 101, 108, 112, 97, 97, 83,…]
type: "Buffer"
```

```
arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
var binary = '';
    var bytes = [].slice.call(new Uint8Array(buffer));
    bytes.forEach((b) => binary += String.fromCharCode(b));
    return window.btoa(binary); 
    }
```

This is how I am binding the image

```
let binaryImg = this.arrayBufferToBase64(this.props.courseDetail?.Picture?.data);
      this.setState({picture : "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+binaryImg})
```

HTML CODE

```
            <img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+this.state.picture}/>
or                 <img src={this.state.picture}/>
```

Comment: You're adding the data prefix twice. Once here: `this.setState({picture : "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+binaryImg})` and again here: `<img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+this.state.picture}/>`. Leave it out when rendering, i.e. `<img src={this.state.picture}/>`

Comment: That was by mistake I did ,but removing that also does not solve the issue nether it gives any error..

Comment: Your `data` array does not actually hold an image, it looks like it holds a pathname that could be referencing an image, `C:\DATEN\GIEB.NET\HelpaaS...`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning,Can you please provide way in which I can upload the image in the binary format in MSSQL Serve and retrieve that Buffer and show the image. I have enough space in database and don't want to have other public folder to store image and path. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should ask a new question about that because that's an entirely different issue.

Comment: This is not a different question I have the data saved by the SQL query in varbinary form and if this is the case than I think varbinary should store string instead of image in binary form. There must be a way different as I didn't intentionally saved the path.